# Repair "Mail App" after downgrade to Lion?

Tags: macos, mail.app, crash

i rollbacked from `Mountain Lion developer preview` to `Lion`.

Works fine, but **Mail App** won't open and crash...

Here crash log:

```
Process:         Mail [791]
Path:            /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Identifier:      com.apple.mail
Version:         5.2 (1257)
Build Info:      Mail-1257000000000000~1
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [192]

Date/Time:       2012-03-02 09:58:58.830 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          14098 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           27
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   6
Anonymous UUID:                      584CEA07-C5AB-4448-B668-6E65B541AF85

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject
  Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iLifeMediaBrowser.framework/Versions/A/iLifeMediaBrowser
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iLifeMediaBrowser.framework/Versions/A/iLifeMediaBrowser
```

I downloaded **MailUpdate10.5.6.dmg** but it won't install. Return me this error before installation:
[image]

any idea?
How can i reinstall Mail? It's possible?

thanks.

---

EDIT:

## Rollback method:

I rollbacked to lion editing `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` file and changing **1.8** to **1.7**.
After that i downloaded lion from app store (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+click) and reinstalled all.
I need only to rechange user and root password (reboot + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, utilities, terminal->resetpassword) and all works fine...

Comment: Beta or pre-release software, with a few exceptions, is off-topic for Ask Different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussion of Mountain Lion is off topic for this site as it is an NDA covered Beta, and your question whilst ostensibly about Lion is implicitley about what Mountain Lion has done to your Mail application/configuration and thus really also off topic.

The only advise I can give you is a generic "use your backup" answer, because I am sure you haven't really just thrown a Beta OS onto your primary machine without taking one, right?

Comment: @stuffle thanks. It's my test machine, not really important if mail won't works, but i won't know why...

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you reverted.  Rollback is an odd term, are you implying you used Time Machine to back out an OS upgrade?

Comment: @stuffle I rollbacked to **lion** editing   `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` file and changing **1.8** to **1.7**. After that i downloaded lion from app store (`ALT+click`) and reinstalled all. I need only to rechange user and root password (`reboot + cmd +r, utilities, terminal->resetpassword`) and all works.

Comment: I am stuck in the same situation. Using Sparrow Mail lite for now.

Comment: Restore /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iLifeMediaBrowser.framework from a Time Machine backup older than when you installed Mountain Lion